# android GPS service best practices

Tags: android, gps

I have an app using the GPS data, I am using

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
```

is there a best practice for using this services. Say if some app already have invoked this I can use the same GPS data instead of invoking the service again.

How can I do this ?

Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make any sense as the `NotificationManager` has nothing to do with GPS and/or GPS data.

Two answer the second part: You can't reuse the GPS data of another app, you can only ask for the last known location and hope that this will not be null. If it is null, you should get the position by yourself by using the `LocationManager` and not the `NotificationManager`.

Comment: thanks WarrenFaith for the answer,  I want to try a more efficient way to use this service, some thing which wont invoke the system service repeatedly.

Comment: sorry i was using  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, accidently posted NotificationManager, sorry for that..

Answer (score 0):

Too receive data from GPS you should use code like this:

```
locationMan= (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
locationMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

LocationListener locationListener= new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            //TODO be sure the new position is really better then the one already had.

            lastPos= location;
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
```

It's a simple listener so every time Android know a change in currente location it will call all listeners, this includes your app and other apps. So the process to discover location is only run once no matter how many listeners are added to the LOCATION_SEVICE.

Once you are done with the GPS use

```
locationMan.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

to remove your listener

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have added the permission for network access and GPS 
Make sure you have added the Google Map API Key into the xml